# Does an open-source psexec clone written in Delphi exist?

Tags: delphi, psexec

I'd like to add [psexec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553) type functionality to an application, but I'd like to have it in native Delphi. Ultimately my goal is to remotely execute a process as SYSTEM, which will require installing a service on the remote machine.

I'm familiar with the [XCmd project](http://www.codeguru.com/Cpp/I-N/network/remoteinvocation/article.php/c5433), which is written in Visual C++. If there already exists a Delphi clone of this program/functionality that would be great. If not, I'll work to convert the XCmd project's logic to Delphi.

Does anyone know of a psexec or xcmd clone for Delphi?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[RunAsSys](http://blog.delphi-jedi.net/2008/05/08/runassys-10-preview/) comes close (doesn't work remotely though), it enables you to run something as system, my [RunInSession](http://www.remkoweijnen.nl/blog/2007/11/08/how-to-launch-a-process-in-a-terminal-session-2/) tool has the ability to start a process in any session and remotely